# how to find max element from dictionary that has list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sublist

I'm a newbie to python, i was thinking of writing a function that basically outputs the largest among sublists present inside a dictionary based on a threshold value.

ex: `champs = create_champion_index({'a': [[0, 10], [1, 20], [2,15]], 'b': [[0, 20], [1, 15], [2, 10]]}, 2)`

```
 >>champs['a']
   [[1, 20], [2, 15]]
 >>champs['b']
   [[0, 20], [1, 15]]
```

So based on the threshold value it should output the sublists that has the largest value. In my example, since i mentioned 2 to be my threshold value the output of term 'a' displays the two biggest lists in ascending order.

Comment: `print(sorted(d["a"],key=sum)[-2:])`

Comment: the threshold value isn't fixed to be 2, it may vary at times, can you be more specific with your solution so that i can understand @PadraicCunningham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have small sublists for simplicity you can sort and return the last `n` sublists after sorting,this presumes *biggest* to be the sublists with largest sum if you mean has the largest subelement change `sum` to `max`:

```
def create_champion_index(d, n):
    new_d = {}
    # iterate over dict items key/values
    for k, v in d.items():
        # add `n` highest summed sublists from each value/list 
        new_d[k] = sorted(v, key=sum,reverse=True)[:n]
    return new_d # return new dict to access later

champs = create_champion_index({'a': [[0, 10], [1, 20], [2,15]], 'b': [[0, 20], [1, 15], [2, 10]]}, 2)

print(champs['a'])
print(champs['b'])
[[1, 20], [2, 15]]
[[0, 20], [1, 15]]
```

You can do it in a couple more lines without sorting but for short lists it is fine to use sorted. I also presume you mean **descending** order not **ascending** as whether it is sum or max both outputs are in decsending order.

You need to add more logic to catch when a key does not exist and there are not at least `n` sublists.

Comment: uh i'm only supposed to pass a dictionary that has list of lists and the threshold value, 2 parameters to the function. In that case how to modify your function to suit my need ??

Comment: i'll be specifying my key on runtime for which i would like to see the output..as i've shown in my example above

Comment: hey can you also help me to count all the sublists that contains a particular element in tat list ?? as in, i have [['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']] now if i call >>result['a'] in runtime the output has to be 3 as 'a' is present in three sublists ..can you help on this plz ?

Comment: @Wolf, I can point you in the right direction, use a collections.Counter dict, look at the examples in the docs, it is very easy to use. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter one or two lines of code will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "threshold" here, but I'll go with your variable name.  So, I understand "threshold" to be the (maximum) number of items from each list to be output, and you want create_champion_index() to be the function that does this.  I'm also not sure what you mean by "largest" sublist.  You don't mean "longest" because all your sublists are 2 elements long.  You might mean the sublist that has the largest individual element in it.  I'll assume that this is what you mean.

The following seems to do what you want:

```
mydict = {'a': [[0, 10], [1, 20], [2,15]], 'b': [[0, 20], [1, 15], [2, 10]]}

def create_champion_index(in_dict, threshold=2):
    from heapq import nlargest
    from itertools import count
    retdict = {}
    for key in in_dict:
        this_list = in_dict[key]
        this_list_sublists_sorted = [sorted(x, reverse=True) for x in this_list]
        max_ndcs = nlargest(threshold, zip(this_list_sublists_sorted, count()))
        ndcs = [x[1] for x in max_ndcs]
        retlist = [this_list[i] for i in ndcs]
        retdict[key] = retlist
    return retdict

champs = create_champion_index(mydict, threshold=2)
print champs['a']
print champs['b']
```

Comment: ya that works, but i'm a newbie can you explain your function please ?

Comment: nlargest() finds the n largest elements of an iterable (basically, a list or something that acts like a list).  I did the _sorted thing and max_ndcs because the behavior you wanted wasn't the default Python list comparison operator.  For instance, in Python, `[0, 10] < [1, 5]` because 0 is less than 1, so I first sorted the lists by the largest items.  I could have just used max() also (i.e., instead).  So, I find where in the _sorted list the n largest items occur, and then grab those items from this_list to add to the dictionary.